# iframe to document - jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the iFrame I want to change the html on a parent document...

**iFrame**

```
$("#Name").html("New Name");
```

**Parent html document**

```
<span id="Name">Old Name</span>
```

Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Is the iframe pointing to the same domain as the page containing the iframe?

Comment: yes, it is on the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#Name', window.parent.document).html("New Name");
```

You are basically just setting the scope of the selector to the parent of the iFrame.

Comment: This is why a good understanding of JavaScript is so important before you leap in to libraries...

Comment: I hear ya Chris, unfortunately trial and error is the only option I have at this point in the game. If you have any leads that will better help me to understand lemme know. Thanks